# Expresso Store: How to check if product is already in the cart?

Tags: expresso-store, ecommerce, conditionals, expresso, shopping-cart

This is my first time working with Expresso Store, so forgive me if this question is extremely basic, but...

How do I show in my `{exp:store:product}` tag pair do a test like:

`if product is in cart,
 show 'Product is in your cart',
 with option to add another`

Make sense?

Thanks for any help.
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar question is here:
https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/271/28

That answer may help in your situation... Not sure if it works inside the tag where you are trying to set the conditional.

> **Store: In_Cart Conditionals**
> http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/store-in_cart-conditionals
>
> "This extension adds certain "in_cart" conditionals within Exp:resso
> Store Cart and Checkout tags.
>
> Available variables: `{store:entry_id_in_cart:XX}` and `{store:sku_in_cart:XX}`

Comment: You shouldn't have a problem adding the code within your products tag to show if the item is in the cart.

Answer (score 3):

As of Store 1.6.2 there is a `{qty_in_cart}` variable which allows you to do this on a per-entry basis (though not if your entries contain multiple SKUs).

```
{exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    {qty_in_cart}
{/exp:store:product}
```